# What do you call this piece of hardware with spurs and female threads?

Tags: fasteners

Can someone please tell me what this is called. It came out of a rather cheaply made cat window perch. I wanted to make one more sturdy (other than 1/8" chip board!) but wanted to use this type fastener if possible to go with the other hardware that came with the perch.

Thanks so much!

[image: hardware 1]

[image: hardware 2]

Comment: A very common size for those is 1/4-20, in case you need more hardware...

Comment: As others said, what you have there is commonly called a "tee nut."

Comment: Very handy to have a few. You should be able to pick them up in the hardware section of most big box stores. If you're careful you can reuse them. If you aren't you'll bend the prongs making them difficult to use and likely to spin in your wood.

Answer (score 6):

That's a threaded insert, specifically a tee-nut with spurs. It is designed to be inserted from the opposite side of a drilled hole and accept a bolt; the spurs dig in to keep it from spinning as the bolt is tightened. Threaded inserts are sometimes used for strength, but more often are used where a connection may be assembled and disassembled (or tightened and loosened) many times and the designer doesn't want it to wear out as it would if a screw was used that way.

Comment: I've always known this as a tee-nut, but have understood threaded inserts to be just an insert without any flange. I guess threaded insert is more so the category that both types of fasteners fall under.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find these on search using the term "wood tee nut".

There are a variety of different forms. There is one that looks like this one except without the "tangs", having small holes in the flange instead where brads or small nails can be used to keep it from falling out or rotating while it's being tightened.